# How many times the counter gets incremented?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

In the loop:

int counter=0;

for(i=0;i<10;i++)

for(j=i+1;j<10;j++)

for(k=j+1;k<10;k++)

for(l=k+1;l<10;l++)

for(m=l+1;m<10;m++)

counter++;

The answer for this counter is 10C5. i Actually don't understand how it is 10C5 ? 
10c5= 10*9*8*7*6/(5!).

Is this five factorial the redundancy . I'm having lot of confusions ? Can somebody help me out by explaining it in a better way ? Like,why we need to go for combinations here ?

Comment: If question is not clear,please do let me know ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$0\le i<j<k<l<m\le 9$

You just pick up 5 different numbers from 10 numbers.

Comment: So,now there is now only one way to arrange,so we go for combinations ? like if you choose 1,2,3,4,5 then any other arrangement of 12345(i.e13245,...) etc not possible !! So,we go for combinations ? Is that right ?

Comment: Yes，and when is 6, you can never choose the other four numbers.

Comment: @ eccstartup Thanks for spending your wonderful time for answering my question ! :)